# Rescue simultaneous errors raised inside threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading, exception

With the following script

```
threads = [
  Thread.new { Thread.current.abort_on_exception = true; raise 'err' },
  Thread.new { Thread.current.abort_on_exception = true; raise 'err' },
]

begin
  threads.each(&:join)
rescue RuntimeError
  puts "Got Error"
end
```

Half the time I get the expected "Got Error" with exit 0 and the other half I get `test.rb:3:in block in <main>': err (RuntimeError)`.

Shouldn't rescue be able to handle this? If not what might be some alternative solutions for two threads raising an error simultaneously?

I've considered not using `abort_on_exception = true` but the problem is that if the first thread has, say `sleep(10)` before the `raise`, the second thread, which errors immediately, won't get caught until 10 seconds is up (due to the order of the `threads` array).

Ruby MRI version:
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin15]

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Update**

jruby-9.1.6.0 doesn't seem to have this problem. Possibly because the inherent thread safeness of it. It always prints `Got Error` without any exceptions. Unfortunately, JRuby is not on option for us.

Comment: Interesting, it even fails when everything is wrapped in a `begin/rescue` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few pieces of the puzzle here.

---

Firstly, the program only waits for the main thread to finish:

```
Thread.new { Thread.current.abort_on_exception = true; raise 'Oh, no!' }

puts 'Ready or not, here I come'
```

The above may or may not raise the error.

---

Secondly, if you join on a thread, an exception raised by that threads is re-raised by the joined thread from the `#join` method:

```
gollum = Thread.new { raise 'My precious!!!' }

begin
  gollum.join
rescue => e
  # Prints 'My precious!!!'
  puts e.message
end
```

Now at that point, the execution is returned to the thread that joined. It is no longer joined to the thread that caused the error or any other thread. The reason it's not joined to other threads is because you can only join one thread at the time. `threads.each(&:join)` actually joins you to the first, when it ends - to the second and so on:

```
frodo = Thread.new { raise 'Oh, no, Frodo!' }
sam   = Thread.new { raise 'Oh, no, Sam!' }

begin
  [frodo, sam].each(&:join)
rescue => e
  puts e.message
end

puts 'This is the end, my only friend, the end.'
```

The above prints

> Oh, no, Frodo!
>   This is the end, my only friend, the end.

---

Now lets put it together:

```
frodo = Thread.new { Thread.current.abort_on_exception = true; raise 'Oh, no, Frodo!' }
sam   = Thread.new { Thread.current.abort_on_exception = true; raise 'Oh, no, Sam!' }

begin
  [frodo, sam].each(&:join)
rescue => e
  puts e.message
end

puts 'This is the end, my only friend, the end.'
```

**Many things can happen here. What is of importance is, if we manage to join (we don't get an error before that), the rescue will catch the exception in the main thread from whichever thread manages to raise it first and then continue after the rescue. After that, the main thread (and thus the program) may or may not finish before the other thread raises its exception.**

---

Let examine some possible outputs:

> ex.rb:1:in `block in ': Oh, no, Frodo! (RuntimeError)

Frodo raised his exception before we joined.

> Oh, no, Sam!
>   This is the end, my only friend, the end.

After we joined, Sam was the first to raise an error. After we printed the error message in the main thread, we also printed the end. Then the main thread finished, before Frodo could raise his error.

> Oh, no, Frodo!ex.rb:2:in `block in ': Oh, no, Sam! (RuntimeError)

We managed to join. Frodo was the first to raise, we rescued and printed. Sam raised before we could print the end.

> Oh, no, Sam!
>   This is the end, my only friend, the end.ex.rb:1:in `block in ': Oh, no, Frodo! (RuntimeError)

(Very rarely) We managed to get to the rescue. Sam raised an error first and we printed it from the main thread. We printed the end. Just after the print, but before the main thread is terminated, Frodo managed to jab his error as well.

---

As for a possible solution, you just need as many rescues as there are threads that might raise. Note that I also put the thread creation in the safeguarded block to ensure we catch potential errors before joins as well:

```
def execute_safely_concurrently(number_of_threads, &work)
  return if number_of_threads.zero?

  begin
    Thread.new(&work).join
  rescue => e
    puts e
  end

  execute_safely_concurrently(number_of_threads.pred, &work)
end

execute_safely_concurrently(2) do
  Thread.current.abort_on_exception = true
  raise 'Handle me, bitte!'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for expanding on the issue. It's very clear with these examples. My output always seems to be the 2nd and 3rd of your above possible outputs (its about 50/50). I'm still trying to find a workaround in MRI (JRuby doesn't seem to have the problem)

Comment: @nolanpro, you have exactly the same cases, I just added more prints to make it easier to understand what is happening. You get the error if one of the threads raises an error before you reach the `join`. You get `Got Error` if an error isn't raised before the `join` and the program exits directly after the rescue. You get both very rarely if no error was raised before the `join` and the second error is raised after the rescue just as the program was about to exit.

Comment: If you are still not convinced, try putting `sleep 5` in a few places. If you puts it directly after the threads creation and before the `begin` block, you should consistently get the error. This is because one of the threads has enough time to raise before you reach the join.

Comment: Instead of that, you could put the sleep at the end of your program (after the closing `end`). You will consistently **not** get just `Got Error`. The reason is that either a thread will raise before you reach the `join` (aka you get only the error) or you rescue one of the errors and then the other thread has enough time to raise as well (aka you get both the print and the error).

Comment: @nolanpro, added a solution as well.

Comment: Thanks I didn't think about wrapping each thread in it's own rescue block. The only problem here is the join call blocking execution. For example, if the first thread did work that took 5 seconds and the second raised immediately, we would still have to wait the 5 seconds before getting to the next thread.

I modified your example to do the work asynchronously but I still get the errors, even with multiple rescues :\

Comment: after playing with your example I think I found a solution that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After looking at @ndn's idea of wrapping each thread in it's own rescue. It looks like this solves the problem. Here is his modified example that doesn't block execution on join.

```
@threads = []
def execute_safely_concurrently(&work)
  begin
    @threads << Thread.new(&work)
  rescue RuntimeError => e
    puts "Child Thread Rescue: #{e}"
  end
end

execute_safely_concurrently do
  Thread.current.abort_on_exception = true
  sleep(3)
  raise 'Handle me, bitte 1!'
end

execute_safely_concurrently do
  Thread.current.abort_on_exception = true
  raise 'Handle me, bitte 2!'
end

begin
  @threads.each(&:join)
rescue RuntimeError => e
  puts "Main Thread Rescue: #{e}"
end
```